# Stack , data and address space limits on an Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory-usage, virtual-memory, limits

I am running an Ubuntu server which has around 5000 users. The users are allowed to SSH in to the system.

So in order to cap the memory used up by a process I have  capped the `address space` limits using `limits.conf`. So my question is , should I be limiting the `data` and `stack` ? I feel that is not required since I am capping `address space`. Are there any pitfalls if I do not cap  the `stack` and `data` limits?